# Add color to div using name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below currently gives both divs red css, I would like to change color uniquely for each div.

```
<div class="foo" name="red">red</div>
<div class="foo" name="blue">blue</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $('.foo').each(function() {
   var color = $('.foo').attr('name');
   $(this).css('color',color);
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Function attr gets attribute of first element.

Comment: have you got a js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).css('color',color);
});
```

Comment: That is a copy of what he has got

Comment: This one changes the second `'.foo'` to `this`

Comment: It is not. First line of function is different.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('.foo').css('color', function() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QjxB9/).

The anonymous function, passed to `css()` iterates over each of the elements returned by the selector, hence `this` refers, in each case, to the currently-iterated element.

Note the use of `getAttribute('name')`, this is because the `div` has no `name` property (the attribute is not valid, outside of an `input`, `select`, `button`, etc... elements).

That being the case I'd *also* suggest using custom `data-*` attributes to store the colours, for example:

```
<div class="foo" data-color="red">red</div>
<div class="foo" data-color="blue">blue</div>
```

And using the jQuery:

```
$('.foo').css('color', function() {
    return $(this).data('color');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QjxB9/1/).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: I like this because it looks cleaner

Comment: Cleaner and, I think, more readable. Plus it avoids unnecessary, and *repeated*, use of the `each()` and `attr()` methods to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it chooses the first foo element.

you should try and use the selector $(this)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want...Plz clean up the code..

```
<div class="foo" name="blue">Hola</div>

<div class="foo" name="red">Hello</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("div").each(function() {
var color = $('.foo').attr('name');
document.write("color got is: "+color);
color=$(this).attr('name');
$(this).css('background-color',color);

document.write("   now color is: "+color)
```